# Is the set $Z_n = \{ 0, 1, . . . , n-1 \}$ for $n ≥ 1$ is a group under addition modulo n?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The set $Z_n = \{ 0, 1, . . . , n-1 \}$ for $n ≥ 1$ is a group under addition modulo n. For any $j > 0$ in $Z_n$, the inverse of $j$ is $n - j$.
This group is usually referred to as the *group of integers modulo n*.

My understanding of this is as following, please let me know if I have gotten the main idea.

Let's pick $Z_3$ as an example.

Then the members of this group is $0,1,2$
let $j=2$ then $n-j=3-2=1$

it says the inverse of $j$ is $n - j$, by definition, an inverse in a group is such ab=identity. And here the identity is 0 under addition.

therefore, 2+1=3 and 3 mod 3 =0 which is the identity.

This applies to any n in $Z_n$

So, it satisfies as a group?

Comment: does it fit the other group axioms ?

Comment: @Roddy macPhee It has an identity, it also works with associative law, it got an inverse. So, it does!

Comment: You only showed j=2 had an inverse.  You didn't show any of the other terms did.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a group, but you need to check more rigorously. Three conditions:

1. Identity element: $a+0=0+a=0$ for all $a\in G$.
2. Inverses: If $a\in G$ then there exists $b\in G$ such that $a+b=b+a=0$.
3. Associativity: If $a,b,c\in G$ then $a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c$

Let $n>0$ and consider $\Bbb{Z}_n$.
Associativity follows immediately since $[a]+[(b+c)]=[a+(b+c)]=[(a+b)+c]=[a+b]+[c]$.

Let $[0]_n$ denote the class of $0$ modulo n.  Then $[a]+[0]=[a+0]=[a]$ for all $a\in\Bbb{Z}_n$. Therefore 1 is satisfied. For 2, let $[a]$ be an element of $\Bbb{Z}_n$ and consider $[n-a]$ as you pointed. Then $[a]+[n-a]=[a+(n-a)]=[a+(-a+n)]=[(a-a)+n]=[n]=[0]$.

Comment: Typo in condition 1. Also, we need another condition - Closure Property (If $x, y \in G \implies x+y \in G$) Though that's trivial.